# Mozilla Firefox forbid removing an addon

Tags: linux, firefox, security, firefox-extensions

I want to create a safe environment in my browser with a couple of extensions that I DON'T want to be deleted by users.
I tried using Private Fox to forbid access to `about:addons` page but I found out that user can remove an extension by simply right-clicking its browser-action icon and choosing "Remove Extension" from a context menu.

Is there a way to prevent this and hide that option from a menu?

Upd: Firefox runs on Linux machines

Comment: [Prevent users from disabling or uninstalling a Firefox addon - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139522/prevent-users-from-disabling-or-uninstalling-a-firefox-addon)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that question and answer and I'd like to add that their solutions are Windows based and therefore not suitable for Linux

Answer (score 4):

So, I asked a question at support.mozilla.com and got an answer - policies. As described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson)  and [here (Github)](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md) I can use "Extension" policy and add required add-ons in "Locked" category, effectively forbidding users from uninstalling named extensions. Actually a very powerful tool, it's a shame I haven't found it earlier